# C# HtmlAgilityPack : startIndex cannot be larger than length of string

Tags: c#, html-parsing, html-agility-pack

I'm trying to do something like this :

```
var document = htmlWeb.Load(searchUrl);
var hotels = document.DocumentNode.Descendants("div")
             .Where(x => x.Attributes.Contains("class") &&
             x.Attributes["class"].Value.Contains("listing-content"));

int count = 1;
foreach (var hotel in hotels)
{
    HtmlDocument htmlDoc = new HtmlDocument();
    htmlDoc.OptionFixNestedTags = true;
    htmlDoc.Load(hotel.InnerText);      
    if (htmlDoc.DocumentNode != null)
    {
        var anchors = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.Descendants("div")
                    .Where(x => x.Attributes.Contains("class") &&
                    x.Attributes["class"].Value.Contains("srp-business-name")); // Error Occurring in here //
        foreach (var anchor in anchors)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(anchor.InnerHtml);
        }
    }
}
```

I'm getting results like this :

```
<a href="http://ad.doubleclick.net/clk;234504055;58257942;j?http://www.marriott.com/NYCMQ" class="url  mip-link" data-analytics="{&quot;click_id&quot;:1601,&quot;rank&quot;:1,&quot;act&quot;:1,&quot;FL&quot;:&quot;list&quot;,&quot;target&quot;:&quot;name&quot;,&quot;supermedia&quot;:true}" rel="nofollow">New York Marriott Marquis</a>
<a href="http://www.yellowpages.com/new-york-ny/mip/new-york-marriott-marquis-468349733?lid=1000372156461" class="no-tracks hidden url" data-analytics="{&quot;click_id&quot;:1601,&quot;rank&quot;:1,&quot;act&quot;:1,&quot;FL&quot;:&quot;list&quot;,&quot;target&quot;:&quot;name&quot;,&quot;supermedia&quot;:true}" rel="nofollow"></a>
<span class="external-link">
<img height="15" src="/images/sprites/search/icon-link-external.png" width="16">
</span>
```

And

```
<a href="http://www.yellowpages.com/new-york-ny/mip/courtyard-by-marriott-new-york-manhattan-times-square-south-2198956?lid=178101818" class="url redbold mip-link" data-analytics="{&quot;click_id&quot;:1600,&quot;rank&quot;:2,&quot;act&quot;:1,&quot;FL&quot;:&quot;list&quot;,&quot;target&quot;:&quot;name&quot;,&quot;supermedia&quot;:&quot;&quot;}">Courtyard by Marriott New York Manhattan/Times Square South</a>
```

And so on.

Now I want the `innerHtml` of the anchors tags having `class="url redbold mip-link"`. So I'm doing this :

```
var document = htmlWeb.Load(searchUrl);
var hotels = document.DocumentNode.Descendants("div")
             .Where(x => x.Attributes.Contains("class") &&
             x.Attributes["class"].Value.Contains("listing-content"));

int count = 1;
foreach (var hotel in hotels)
{
    HtmlDocument htmlDoc = new HtmlDocument();
    htmlDoc.OptionFixNestedTags = true;
    htmlDoc.Load(hotel.InnerText);      
    if (htmlDoc.DocumentNode != null)
    {
        var anchors = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.Descendants("div")
                    .Where(x => x.Attributes.Contains("class") &&
                    x.Attributes["class"].Value.Contains("srp-business-name"));
        foreach (var anchor in anchors)
        {
            htmlDoc.LoadHtml(anchor.InnerHtml);
            var hoteltags = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a");
            foreach (var tag in hoteltags)
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(tag.InnerHtml) || !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(tag.InnerHtml))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(tag.InnerHtml);
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

I' getting the first result properly which is `New York Marriott Marquis`  but in the second result an error occurring : 
`startIndex cannot be larger than length of string`. What am I doing wrong ??

Comment: on which line is the exception occurring?

Comment: i strongly believe that this code does not produce the exception you mentioned.

Comment: Keith Payne yes i'm getting this error. and I've updated my question in which i've mentioned as a comment where the error is occuring.

Comment: Sudhakar Tillapudi : I've updated my question in which i've mentioned as a comment where the error is occuring.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the same DOM object for all your operations:

```
foreach (var hotel in hotels)
{
    HtmlDocument htmlDoc = new HtmlDocument();
```

And after that you are using the same object for loading anchor tags:

```
foreach (var anchor in anchors)
        {
            htmlDoc.LoadHtml(anchor.InnerHtml);
```

Just change the document in the second iterator and it should work as expected.

```
  foreach (var anchor in anchors)
            {
                var htmlDocAnchor= new HtmlDocument();
                htmlDocAnchor.LoadHtml(anchor.InnerHtml);// And etc..
```